# \HAR@checkdef alternative in natbib

Tags: citing, natbib, harvard-style

In `harvard` package it is possible to customise missing citations by renewing a special command called `\HAR@checkdef`. Here is an example:

```
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}                  %% Tooltips over text with \pdftooltip
\bibliographystyle{apsr}                 %% (Smith, 2000)
\makeatletter                            %% Replacement of ? with ?? and a tooltip for broken citations (eases problem search in pdf)
\renewcommand{\HAR@checkdef}[2]{\@ifundefined{HAR@df@#1}{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\_}[\escapedkey]\restoreexpandmode%
    \pdftooltip{??}{\escapedkey}\@warning{Citation '#1' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
    {#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

This code replaces a single stanard bold question mark with a double question mark and adds a tooltip into a PDF: (**?**) → (??). By using two question marks as a symbol for something incomplete or wrong I can quickly do `CTRL+F ??` in a large document and instantly assess its readiness.

I've recently moved from `harvard` to `natbib` as it has more options for various brackets around citations, but now I can’t make this trick with a double question mark work again.

What command should I renew or add to be able to customise broken citations in a `natbib`-using document?